# Why SSH is not active on my gitlab server?

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I want to use SSH on my GitLab server. However, I even cannot see the "Clone with SSH" option.
Any idea why it is happening? Or why SSH is inactive on my Gitlab server?

[image]

Comment: This question needs more details about your setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access protocol to GitLab can be set using HTTPS or SSH. This feature should be activated by Admin. Please see this:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/visibility_and_access_controls.html#enabled-git-access-protocols